# Build Windows Phone 7 application at PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-7, mobile, cordova

I'm building my application using PhoneGap Build and all builds are ok with the exception of Windows Phone 7.

Error log:

> "C:\cygwin\tmp\a00dd912-2009-11e1-a9f8-1231390521a2\template\templates\full\GapSolution.sln"
> (default target) (1) ->
>
> "C:\cygwin\tmp\a00dd912-2009-11e1-a9f8-1231390521a2\template\templates\full\GapAppProj.csproj"
> (default target) (2) ->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failure in the compilation is related to the length of the author's name in the `config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a topic at:

http://getsatisfaction.com/nitobi/products/nitobi_phonegap_build

You should also supply your App ID (http://build.phonegap.com/apps/[App ID]) so they can look into the build of your App from their side.